# Form dropdown defaults to '1' each time despite defining selected: @foo.size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a form with the following selection list:

```
<th>Unit Size</th>

   <td><%= f.select :unit_size, options_for_select((1..@foo.bar.bar_type.usize)), {selected: @foo.unit_size} %></td>
```

No matter what foo.unit_size is in the DB, the form always has '1' selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selected option should be passed to `#options_for_select`, not to `#select` as "selected" key :

```
f.select :unit_size, options_for_select((1..@foo.bar.bar_type.usize), @foo.unit_size)
```